# Why is this glass Cycles material casting solid shadows?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

I created a glass cone with black seams (the seams are a diffuse not transparent material).

[image: render with solid shadow]

When I shine light on it, the cone casts a solid shadow. Why is this?

I would like to have a (semi) transparent shadow cast from the glass
and a full shadow from the seams.

Here is the link where you can (hopefully) download the blend file:

[glass cone](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1B3fCpzacVibEE4cDRITV96TzA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: in the future please share the file in a way that doesn't require permission to download.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You did have ***Transparent Shadows*** disabled in the Material Settings.  Once enabled, you can use the ***Light Path*** Node's ***Is Shadow Ray*** to Select between the Glass and Transparency shaders to achieve this effect.

[image]

Comment: maybe the transparent shader should have the same color as the glass

Comment: @MarcClintDion 
Thanks Marc, looks very good! I've copied your node-structure but it gives me no the same result (I've added the picture in your post). Could it be that I have to edit the material of the plane ?

Comment: @Christophe Add a link to the pic in a comment to this answer instead of editing it into the answer. Editing your problems into someone's answer, doesn't really help anyone, including you.

Comment: I see you marked the answer as correct.  I guess this means you got it.  That's good because I re-downloaded your file, reset Blender to factory defaults and tried again and it works for me just as before.  I'm curious about where your problem was.

Comment: "Light Path Node -> Is Shadow Ray" - This is GOLD, thank you. You just solved hours of troubleshooting. I also added a "Subtract" node (Anywhere from 0.1 - 0.5) after "Is Shadow Ray" to adjust the shadow. The shadow now degrades as light passes through multiple panes of glass - as it should.

Answer (score 6):

You need to put a *solidify* modifier on your glass pieces. Or make them thick otherwise.

This way there will be no back-facing polygons for each glass piece, so Cycles doesn't see one huge solid glass pyramid with the inside not empty as it does currently. Such glass pyramid would, in real live, produce this shadow.

Comment: Hi Jerryno,
the glasspieces are solidified, so that's not the issue...

Comment: @Christophe interesting.. what are your transparency bounce settings? can you edit your question and add a screenshot of your nodes or upload the whole file? I was certain the normals were the issue-this is exactly how such glass looks.(

Comment: I added a downloadlink to the file. Thanks for looking at this. Transparency- and shadowsettings in Blender are pretty new to me ...

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your help!

Apparently there was something wrong with the "Ambient Occlusion". Very strange.

**Initial settings 'World'**

[image]

**Result intitial settings and node settings**

(so, solid shadows ==> not good)

[image]

**Change 'World'-settings**

==> put 'Ambient Occlusion" ON and OFF again

[image]

It worked!

Thank you!